# Multiple foreach with two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have been trying to figure this out all day... but can't seem to get it working.

I have this code that works:

```
<?php foreach ($value['options'] as $option) { ?>
<option><?php echo $option; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

and it displays correctly with the array listed as my options. But I wanted a value with each array by splilting another array I had into an option by doing this:

```
<?php foreach ($value['options'] as $option) {
      foreach ($value['cids'] as $cid) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $cid; ?>"><?php echo $option; ?></option>
<?php } } ?>
```

Whenever I do that, it my options are multiplied in every possible way, which I dont want. How would I go about doing something like this

```
<?php foreach ($value['options'] as $option AND $value['cids'] as $cid) { 
    echo $option;
    echo $cid;
 } ?>
```

I know that doesn't work... just want something similar. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your arrays numerically indexed and have the same number of items? You can use a for loop with an increment variable.

Comment: yes, they are equal values. How would I used the for loop with my arrays and it parameters? Im not the best with php, but I understand a good bit of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you all for the answers. It led me to the right direction. Here is what I did to get this working.

```
<?php 

$myoptions = array_combine($value['options'], $value['cid']);
foreach ($myoptions as $option => $cid) { ?>

<option value="<?php echo $cid; ?>"><?php echo $option; ?></option>

<?php }  ?>
```

I did an `array_combine` to echo my values.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php):

```
<?php
$array1 = range(1,5);
$array2 = range(6,10);

$iterator = new MultipleIterator();
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array1));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array2));
foreach($iterator as $items){
        echo $items[0].' - '.$items[1];
}

?>
```

Of course, real old school (you younguns don't know how much `foreach` has spoiled you):

```
<?php
$array1 = range(1,5);
$array2 = range(6,10);

//reset array pointers to be sure
reset($array1);
reset($array2);
while((list(,$a) = each($array1)) && (list(,$b) = each($array2))){
   echo $a .':'.$b.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We assume that both `$value['options']` and `$value['cids']` have the same length `$length`:

```
<?php  for($i=0 ; $i < $length; $i++) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value['options'][$i]; ?>"><?php echo $value['cids'][$i]; ?></option>
    $arr[$i];
<?php } ?>
```

If your array, however, is associative, you can use something like :

```
function getArrayFromIndex($arr, $ind)
{
    $i==0;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($i==$ind)
             return $key;
    }
}
```

to get your Nth element by calling

`getArrayFromIndex($value['options'],$i)`

instead of

`$value['options'][$i]`

Comment: They may have not numeric, not consecutive or not equal keys

Comment: @zerkms ok for not numeric, but if it's not consecutive it would be the same problem as `foreach`

Comment: thanks for this.. I tried it, but it doesnt seem to be working for me. I need to keep my parameters in my variables. `$value['options']`